# IdlingResource isn't registering correctly in TestRule

Tags: android, automation

I've created a very simple IdlingResource implementation in order to demonstrate this behaviour.

Running the test results in my `assertTrue()` firing because `idle = false`.

```
public class BootstrapRuleTest {

    private boolean idle = true;

    @Rule
    public ExternalResource rule = new ExternalResource() {

        @Before
        public void before() {
            IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(new IdlingResource() {
                @Override
                public String getName() {
                    return "Im Unique!";
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isIdleNow() {
                    return idle;
                }

                @Override
                public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback callback) {

                }
            });

            idle = false;

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    idle = true;
                }
            }).start();
        }
    };

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertTrue("Rule broken", idle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register()` doesn't work when it's being called from inside a ExternalResource rule.

If I switch this to a TestWatcher rule then everything works fine.